# RegExp stumper, should be simple

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm usually very good with RegExp, but this one has me stumped.  Here's the javascript snippet:

```
var justDateRegex = '\d+/\d+/\d+';
var dateStr = $('#Dropdown').find(':selected').text();
var onlyDate = dateStr.match(justDateRegex);
console.log('Regex: ' + justDateRegex + ' dateStr: ' + dateStr + ' onlyDate: ' + onlyDate);
```

Here's the output from the console.log

```
Regex: d+/d+/d+ dateStr: 11/23/2013 12:00:00 AM onlyDate: null
```

I would expect the onlyDate to read: 11/23/2013, but its null.  Any ideas why?

Comment: `justDateRegex` is not a RegExp object, it's a string.  It needs to be a RegExp object for this to work.

Comment: The output gives it away: `\d` is interpreted as an escape sequence (like `\n` or `\r`) in the string. Since it's an invalid escape sequence, the `\ ` is ignored and you end up with `d+/d+/d+`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String.match()` expects its parameter to be a RegExp object, not a string.

```
var justDateRegex = /\d+\/\d+\/\d+/;
var dateStr = $('#Dropdown').find(':selected').text();
var onlyDate = dateStr.match(justDateRegex);
```

Comment: `.match(new RegExp(justDateRegex))` would also work, but is more verbose

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yes, but then you'd have to escape the backslashes to prevent them from being interpreted as escape sequence (like `\n` and `\r`) in the string. It just makes more sense to enter a regular expression *as a regular expression* in the code. Unless you need to generate the regular expression dynamically, you don't need a detour via a string and a `RegExp` constructor.

Comment: It didn't like the /stuff/ syntax.  I assume because the included / characters in the regexp.  However, escaping the \ did the trick. Duh.

Comment: @urbadave: Yeah you need to escape the `/` :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have to escape the `\`. Here's a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GgMYb/1/).

```
var justDateRegex = '\\d+/\\d+/\\d+';
var dateStr = '11/23/2013';
var onlyDate = dateStr.match(justDateRegex);
console.log('Regex: ' + justDateRegex + ' dateStr: ' + dateStr + ' onlyDate: ' + onlyDate);
```

Comment: @RocketHazmat - Yeah, that was a typo.